# Apex error : You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: apex, exception, dml, future, http

**Apex error :** You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out.

I get the above error when I try to make two http callout one after the other and store the result in database in between the http calls.

**Below are the apex steps which are done:**

1. DML statement to get the number of HTTP callouts to be made. For ex: if it has two HTTP calls to be made.
2. The first HTTP call is made and then store the result of HTTP callout.
3. Make the next HTTP callout and then store the result of the HTTP callout.

I can't make the HTTP callout as future as I require the output to be displayed to the end user for all the HTTP callout.

Please let me know if the question is not clear, and  how we can handle this scenario.

Comment: check this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326129&mode=1&type=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it absolutely essential that you store the results of the first call out prior to making the second call out? If not you could simply assign your results to variables and persist the records after the second call out returns.

Alternatively, you could still consider using future methods in combination with a UI updates based on data changes pattern like this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_ui_updates_from_data_changes.htm

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform DML before a callout.  Knowledge Article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328873&mode=1&type=1).

You may have to break this up into multiple Apex methods called by the front end, sending responses to the front end and sending them back accordingly.

There may be risks associated with it, so you'll have to determine if this is the right course of action for you.

EDIT: Got the order wrong, updated accordingly.